# Computer does not BOOT, POST, show any image nor react to power button once turned on?

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer, boot

Well I have a Packard Bell Easy.. something, I don't know the model anymore, but it's a 6 years old Desktop and it worked pretty well until last night.

The problem is that when I boot it on the computer doesn't react to anything, the DVD Drive won't open, and the power button where blue light should be visible stays just dark after powering on. Holding the power button for even a minute doesn't turn the machine off. The only way to shut it down it to unplug the power coord.

The monitor when is plugged into any video slot on the PC stays black, but like the computer is asleep, so there is signal but just a black screen, else my monitor would have reported "NO SIGNAL" messages, which it does not. No matter where I insert the video plug, in the on board video or GPU video, it just stays black. When unplugged the monitor ofcourse says "no signal".

On pc startup you can only hear the CPU and the PSU fan but not even a beep or something else, the only thing that happens more is that the disk is spinning up. That's it.

I tried to remove the CPU, GPU, RAM sticks, DVD rom and the HDD from the desktop and only connected the screen to the onboard graphics and the power coord to the desktop, tried to get anything on screen, but the same happen. So it doesn't matter if all parts are connected to the MOBO or not, the same problem persists without any change.

I tried taking out the CMOS battery and let it stand for a while while also unplugged from the power, hit the power button to ensure there is no power left in the pc so everything will reset, but this didn't do the trick. As if this never happend.

What could this be causing?
Can I get this back together?
Could there be power shortage somewhere? USB ports maybe or something?
And.. worst of all: Is my MOBO dead?

The blue power light lights up maybe for half a second when turning on sometimes.

Comment: It doesn't mean there is signal if your screen is black. If there was no signal a "no signal" message would appear only for few seconds, then your monitor would enter power saving mode (black screen).
Have you checked power supply cables, especially the 20/24 pin one?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/8355/how-to-troubleshoot-a-computer-not-booting-up-when-powered-on?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/7766/computer-wont-post-after-power-outage

Comment: Most likely causes: Failed PSU, failed motherboard, failed CPU. A PSU is usually easy to replace, so I would test it with a PSU (power supply unit) from another computer. Other than that, see Techies links and try it with just the board, CPU, CPU fan and power supply. Nothing else is needed, not even RAM. The board should power up and beep (usually 3 times to indicate missing RAM).

Comment: well I tried running the pc with only the mobo (ram,cpu,gpu,disk/dvd/cd drives disconnected from the mobo and the psu), power supply and a monitor connected to the onboard graphics and the problem persists, then it's the mobo or the psu, I will have to aquire a psu to test on.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a PSU issue, I think. If it is not delivering enough power to the mobo then it can't do anything. But at least one of those components is definitely dead, and it's probably the mobo.